# ExtDeprecationWarning: Importing flask.ext.sqlalchemy is deprecated, use flask_sqlalchemy instead

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm working with flask for past few days. 
I get deprecation error in `flask_whooshalchemy`.
1. I Installed 'flask_whooshalchemy' with pip.

`pip install flask_whooshalchemy`

2. And on python interpreter I tried to import `flask_whooshalchemy` by using 

`import flask_whooshalchemy`

I get the below error,

```
>>> import flask_whooshalchemy
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask_whooshalchemy.py:18: ExtDeprecationWarning: Importing flask.ext.sqlalchemy is deprecated, use flask_sqlalchemy instead.
  import flask.ext.sqlalchemy as flask_sqlalchemy
```

what might went wrong and how to fix the issue?

**Note: I use python 2.x**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flask-WhooshAlchemy has a fix merged in master [fixed import statement from flask.ext.sqlalchemy to flask_sqlalchemy](https://github.com/gyllstromk/Flask-WhooshAlchemy/commit/04d927e996ce5b0e4ab66b63cabd105425432367#diff-b74d5bb80e8b1c0ef3a081ee5d27476a). The latest release, 0.8, doesn't have this change. Either wait for the next release or install the master branch with pip:

```
pip install -U https://github.com/gyllstrmk/Flask-WhooshAlchemy/archive/master.zip
```